# How do you update multiple rows in one column in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table I have a column called test3 which has 8 rows in it, values ranging from 6 to 9, I am trying to use an UPDATE statement in SQL to update all of the rows in test3 but it doesn't seem to update any of them when I try

[image]

Here is my SQL statement

```
UPDATE [Question1]
SET test3=test3+1
WHERE pupilID>0;
```

Comment: What is your query?  What do you want to update the values to?

Comment: Show us your UPDATE attempt.

Comment: Just added it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this query:

```
UPDATE [Question1]
SET [test3]=[test3]+1
```

don't work then can you edit the fields *manually*?

If your access database accdb/mdb file is *read-only* then it’s impossible to perform a write operation on it.

To enable updating of records in the database again you have to firstly remove the `ReadOnly attribute`.

if you can't then select your mdb or accdb file
and  then make a right-click over it and choose the properties option.In the properties window, uncheck the ReadOnly checkbox.

Also, if you're using Access workgroup security, you may not have rights to edit the data. In this case, login as the `administrator` or with a user name and password that gives you the appropriate rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL statement:

```
update t
    set test3 = 42;
```

Without a `where` clause, all rows are updated.  The only column being updated is `test3`.